# Orthonormal Basis for Convex Functions

Tags: reference-request, fa.functional-analysis, convexity, hilbert-spaces

Are there any orthonormal bases for strictly convex functions $f: \mathbb{R}^n\ni x \mapsto \mathbb{R},\ x\ne y\implies f\left(\alpha x+\left(1-\alpha\right)y\right) \lt \alpha f(x)+(1-\alpha)f(y) \wedge \alpha\in(0,1)$?

The subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$ on which $f$ is defined can be restricted in any appropriate way e.g. unit cube, unit sphere, etc.

edit:
what I want to do, is to assign elements $p\in\mathbb{R}^n$ to the vertices of a complete, finite metric graph $G(V,E)$ in a way that the $\left(p_i,\sum_{V\setminus i}w(e_{ij})\right)\in\mathbb{R}^{n+1}$ are in convex configuration, and to determine a convex function $f:\mathbb{R}^n\ni x\mapsto \mathbb{R}$ with $f(p_i)=\sum_{V\setminus i}w(e_{ij})\ \forall i,j\quad \wedge\quad \sum\|p_j-p_i\|=1\quad \wedge\quad \min_{i\ne j}{\|p_j-p_i\|}=max\quad$ for some fixed $2\le n\le |V|$; those conditions do not yet rule out ambiguity w.r.t. isometric transformation of the points, but that can be easily fixed.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by that? (convex functions do not form a linear space, etc.)

Comment: @fedja the nonexistence of such bases would answer my question in the negative sense; do you have any references or counterexamples that prove the nonexistence of what I am looking for?

Comment: Don't you need some extra structure, e.g., $f\in C(\mathbb{R} ^2)$ or $f\in L_2$? For sure you'll need a Hilbert space structure

Comment: @AmirSagiv the required structure could be part of an answer; I am looking for bases (resp. decompositions) of  continuous convex functions, that would allow for the successive approximation of a convex function that would be the optimal solution of an optimization problem, resp. checking the existence of such a function.

Comment: So you're looking for an orthonormal basis, such that the projection of any convex function onto the space spanned by that basis is guaranteed to also be convex?

Comment: @Wouter thats exactly what I am looking for

Comment: Something like this? http://dx.doi.org/10.1007/s00211-017-0884-8

Comment: @ChristianClason its not a 100% of what I am looking for, but it qualifies as a good answer

Comment: @ManfredWeis Sorry, I missed the "strict" part; in this case I'm not sure if this is helpful. Without the strictness requirement, you could also start with a finite number of affine hyperplanes tangent at given points (instead of the infinitely many that characterize any convex function), see https://doi.org/10.1007/s10107-014-0756-2. As fedja mentions, ONB is not the right concept here. Could you add some details on what you would like to use them for?